# F5 iRule for UIE - Extracting a value from HTTP response payload/body

Tags: f5, big-ip

We are trying to write a iRule for the BIG-IP universal persistence module.
Our mission is to extract and persist from a HTTP response payload/body an application unique identifier (something like a seesionid for us).
Then use it in a consecutive HTTP requests.
Note, this unique identifier return in text/xml/soap-xml response formats and there is no cookie involve here.

We're having problem to write the TCL code for the extraction of our custom unique identifier from the  HTTP response payload/body.
We have checked these manuals and did not find example for this kind of functionality:

1. https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.HTTP_RESPONSE.ashx
2. https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.HTTP__payload.ashx

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [example with jsession IDs](https://devcentral.f5.com/codeshare/weblogic-jsessionid-persistence) that should get you started with basic persistence flow, and [this example](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/terminal-server-persistence) gives you an idea on how to work with payload data.